# Show that $f$ is a ring isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the ring of Gaussian integers $D=\lbrace a+bi\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z \rbrace}$, where $i \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $i^2=-1$. Consider the map $f$ from $D$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ sending $i$ to the class of $x$ modulo $x^2+1$. Show that $f$ is a ring isomorphism.

I got a confusion in this question. I don't understand the map sending $i$ to the class of $x$ modulo $x^2+1$. Can anyone help me to clear my confusion?

EDIT: I am having trouble to show the map is injective and surjective. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a quotient ring. Its elements are equivalence classes modulo the ideal $(x^2+1)$. Thus, a typical element in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$ is of the form $f(x)+(x^2+1)$ where $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ and $(x^2+1)$ is the ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$ generated by $x^2+1$. So, the map $D\to \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$ sends $i$ to $x+(x^2+1)$.

The question as stated does not actually make any sense. The reason is that the given information does not describe a function from all of $D$. What the question is really trying to say is that there is a (in effect unique) ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$ with the properties that $f(a)=a+(x^2+1)$ for all $a\in \mathbb Z$ and $f(i)=x+(x^2+1)$.

Comment: the map is defined on the generators of the corresponding $\mathbb{Z}$ modules. That's why one send's $i$ to $\overline{x}$

Comment: I have a question (algebra is a continuing struggle for me): When you write $(x^2+1)$ is the ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$ generated by $x^2+1$, do you mean $(x^2+1) = [x^2+1 ]\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (I am using [] as 'ordinary' brackets)? Also, would a typical element be of the form $f(x)+(x^2+1)g(x)$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes and yes (for the latter yes, it is conditioned if by typical you mean typical in the quotient ring).

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Thanks! Is the notation $(...)$ standard for 'ideal generated by'? (Sorry for all the low level questions.)

Comment: again: yes :) :)

Comment: @IttayWeiss: At the risk of aggravating the SE Gods, thanks again!

Comment: I am having trouble to show the map is injective and surjective, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, you have also to specify what happens to the integers.

And then, it's the *inverse* map that occurs more naturally in the context of the structure of simple extensions.

Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi : & \Bbb{Z}[x] \to \Bbb{Z}[i]\\
&a \mapsto a, \quad \text{for $a \in \Bbb{Z}$}\\
&x \mapsto i,\end{align}$$
which is uniquely determined by the [universal property of polynomial rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Quotient_ring_of_K.5BX.5D).

This is clearly surjective, and its kernel is $(x^{2} + 1)$, since $x^{2} + 1$ is the [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28field_theory%29) of $i$ over $\Bbb{Z}$. Now apply the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem_2).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I'm quite correctly interpreting your question, but I'll answer to the best of my ability. Start out with $\mathbb{Z}[x]$; the image of $x$ under the map $\pi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, which let's denote $\overline{x}$, is such that $\overline{x}^2 + 1 = 0$, or that $\overline{x}^2 = -1$. So you can see why it is reasonable to identify $i$ with $\overline{x}$ (abstractly $i$ is a symbol, that follows the "grammar rule" that $i^2 = -1$).

To show that if is a ring homomorphism, just show that the map is well defined, and that it is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The map in general format will be $f(a+ib)=a+bx + \langle x^2 +1 \rangle$
it is a ring homomorphism since $f(a+ib +c +id )= (a+bx +c+dx) + \langle x^2 +1 \rangle = a+bx +\langle x^2 +1 \rangle c+dx +\langle x^2 +1 \rangle =f(a+ib)+f(c+id)$

Comment: you also need to consider products...